# no result asp REPLACE function

Tags: string, replace

varitem = match.SubMatches(1)
varitemthis = p_variables_list.Item(varitem)

result of

```
response.write  match.Value &" "& varitemthis &" "&varitem & "<br>"
```

is

```
{{name}} rrrr name
{{site_root}} www.site.com/ site_root
{{mail}} sdddddsssdfffrrrsdf@ssrsssr.com mail
{{code}} code
```

result of

```
p_template = Replace(p_template, match.Value, varitem)
response.write p_template
```

all right, but

```
p_template = Replace(p_template, match.Value, varitemthis)
response.write p_template
```

**nothing... why? what's wrong?**

Comment: You need to make your questions more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things...

Remember that the Replace function is case sensitive

Do some basic trouble-shooting by making sure you have values.

```
Response.Write "Original p_template = " & p_template 
Response.Write "match.Value = " & match.Value 
Response.Write "varitemthis = " & varitemthis

p_template = Replace(p_template, match.Value, varitemthis)

Response.Write "New p_template = " & p_template
```

Answer (score 0):

In Classic ASP the **Replace** function is not case sensitive.